# OSMdroid - Replace empty grid background when no tile available (offline)

Tags: java, android, offline, tiles, osmdroid

I'm using OSMdroid library in my project to display map tiles (it's a shape with lines and blank background) from my company local sever in my app. The thing is when I use the app in offline mode and I browse the map shows an empty grey grid background for the tiles that aren't in the cache, and I want to change that empty grey grid for an blank background image/tile.

The only workaround that I've found to achieve this is the following:

Add a tile overlay and set setLoadingBackgroundColor and setLoadingLineColor to Color.WHITE, and then set the TileSource from the local server from OnlineTileSourceBase. I know this is not quite performant, so is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance!

```
    final ITileSource tileSource = new OnlineTileSourceBase(...)
    {
        @Override
        public String getTileURLString(MapTile aTile) {
            return getBaseUrl()  + aTile.getX() + "+" + aTile.getY() + "+" + aTile.getZoomLevel();
        }
    };

    tileProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(context, tileSource);

    tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(tileProvider , context);
    tilesOverlay.setLoadingBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    tilesOverlay.setLoadingLineColor(Color.WHITE);

    this.map.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);
    this.map.setTileSource(tileProvider.getTileSource());

    map.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is an example on adding a secondary tile overlay. That's useful for when you need another raster graphics overlay on top of the map imagery.

You can also change the loading lines and background for the existing and default tiles overlay. This should get you going

`mMapView.getOverlayManager().getTilesOverlay().setLoadingBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mMapView.getOverlayManager().getTilesOverlay().setLoadingLineColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Comment: In fact several overlay to display on top of the map imagery, and that did the trick! thank you very much spy!